# How to get Request.ApplicationPath in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

On my razor view, I am wanting to put all of my jQuery into a separate JS file and then reference that file on the view with `@Scripts.Render`.

On my view, I have a section jQuery that looks like this:

```
var settings = {};
settings.baseUri = '@Request.ApplicationPath';
var submissionUrl = "";
if (settings.baseUri === "/ProjectNameOnServer") {
    submissionUrl = settings.baseUri + "/api/apiControllerName/apiControllerMethodName/";
} else {
    submissionUrl = settings.baseUri + "api/apiControllerName/apiControllerMethodName/";
}
```

This section of code allows me to test submitting forms with api on both my localhost and live on the server without me having to change the url.

If I am testing on my localhost, then `@Request.ApplicationPath == /`, but if I test on my server then `@Request.ApplicationPath == /ProjectNameOnServer`.

I was wondering how I could achieve getting these same values but without the use of Razor, and instead only with jQuery.

I have tried:

```
var settings = {};
settings.baseUri = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
```

but then `settings.baseUri == http://localhost:xxxxx`.  I just need exactly what `@Request.ApplicationPath` is giving me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `location.host` to conditionally create relative path

```
settings.baseUri = location.host.includes('localhost') ? '/' : '/ProjectNameOnServer';
```

Comment: Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'

Comment: OK..use `indexOf('localhost')>-1`